# Is there any reason why BackupExec 2010 cant find any Windows 7 machines?

Tags: windows-7, symantec, backupexec

If I install RAWS (from the backup exec directory) on Windows XP machines, my backup exec server is able to find them quite easily. Is Win7 not allowing RAWS to publish?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to push install the Remote Agent to a computer running Windows 7, you may be required to start the Remote Registry Service before the install.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Windows 7 machine still have it's firewall turned on and if so, did you open the ports needed for BackupExec agent to run?

Comment: The firewall is definitely off. One would think they would at least be able to see each other.

Comment: Do you have Backup Exec 2010 or 2010 R2 (version 13.0.4164)?

Comment: Version 13.0 Rev 4164 for the media server/admin console. Version 3.1 Rev 3.43.17a for the DLO.